# Upgrade TypeScript interface to child interface?

Tags: typescript

In JavaScript, it is common practice to "upgrade" objects, i.e. add on temporary metadata. Let's say I have the interface `Obj`:

```
interface Obj {
  someProperty: number;
}
```

I want to display a list of objects using Angular, and I want to upgrade my list of `Obj` objects from the backend REST API to `DisplayableObj` objects.

```
interface DisplayableObj extends Obj {
  displayProperty: string;
}
```

So I create a translation function:

```
function upgrade(obj: Obj): DisplayableObj {
  // This is the question topic right here
}
```

I currently know of three ways that I could upgrade an `Obj` to the child type `DisplayableObj`:

1. **Type-cast the object for every display property I set.** (excerpt from `upgrade`)

   ```
   (obj as DisplayableOb).displayProperty = obj.someProperty.toString();
   return obj as DisplayableObj;
   ```

   This can be very verbose if I set a bunch of display properties, and I don't want to instantiate a temporary `DisplayableObj` variable in the `upgrade` function because that could be costly if I map massive datasets using the function--so the only solution for that is to cast the `Obj` parameter for each and every property I set when upgrading it.
2. **Have only one type and make display properties optional.**

   ```
   interface Obj {
     someProperty:     number;
     displayProperty?: string;
   }

   function upgrade(obj: Obj): Obj {
     obj.displayProperty = obj.someProperty.toString();
     return obj;
   }
   ```

   No, *no*. I work on a large project that uses enriched types all over the place, and having a ton of optional properties defeats the purpose of TypeScript, since you end up having to look very carefully to make sure you actually have certain metadata at various points in the code.
3. **Create a new instance of the child type, and pass in parent properties.**

   ```
   function upgrade(obj: Obj): DisplayableObj {
     return {
       someProperty: obj.someProperty,
       displayProperty: obj.someProperty.toString()
     }
   }
   ```

   No! This is not even modifying the original object--it's creating a new one altogether.

**The solution: *syntax sugar***

```
function upgrade(obj: Obj): DisplayableObj {
  return obj -> DisplayableObj{
    displayProperty: obj.someProperty.toString()
  }
}
```

That `->` operator is just pseudo-code for what I'm looking for, an *upgrade* operator, which will really just get boiled out in the transpilation to JavaScript, but is necessary for clean expression in TypeScript. Does such a thing exist, or should I make an issue on the GitHub?

Comment: "In JavaScript, it is common practice to "upgrade" objects,"  Funny how no strongly typed language has the need for any such thing...  Maybe don't do that?

Comment: Not sure that I follow... Is this an idea from a feature/capability from another language? If so can you provide a link or language and feature name?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't loop over your objects and apply the map operator to convert each one to another object with the added properties?

Comment: Why do you say for option #1 that it could be costly to use another variable? If you create a variable that is just the `obj` parameter cast as the `DisplayableObj` type no new object is created. The overhead would be the pointer to that object. Additionally, I have a feeling that the JS engines would optimize that variable right out as they would see that it wasn't needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Closest thing to your proposed syntax is using [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to modify the original object:

```
function upgrade(obj: Obj): DisplayableObj {
    return Object.assign(obj, {
        displayProperty: obj.someProperty.toString()
    });
}
```

Here, `assign`'s return type  `Obj & {displayProperty:string}` gets matched against function's return type `DisplayableObj`, type errors will be reported in case of missing properties.

Note that this requires creating an extra object to pass as the second argument to `assign`, which might not be what you want.

Alternatively, use casting, but define a type alias save on characters:

```
type D = DisplayableOb
(obj as D).displayProperty = obj.someProperty.toString();
```

Comment: What do you mean by this? "Note that this requires creating an extra object, which might not be what you want." In the example you gave, no extra object is created.

Comment: @DanielWStrimpel It does create a second object. When you use `{}`, you create a new object in Javascript. So you are creating a new object of the child type and assigning its properties from the original.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know TypeScript had a type intersection, or whatever you'd call the `&` in that context. Not perfect, but better than what I was doing.

Comment: @Sam Yeah, if you do `Object.assign({}, ...)` however the example doesn't have that... the original is the target object and is getting changed. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

Comment: @Sam I was originally thinking that it was being stated that the `Object.assign` was returning a new object, but I'm thinking that you guys are speaking about the new source object that is being created.

Comment: I edited my answer to clarify what I meant, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @Sam They are indeed called [intersection types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types). Looks like `Object.assign` is overloaded to return an intersection type for up to 4 arguments, after which it falls back to `any`. That's probably fine, as generally you see it used with 2-3 arguments.

Comment: @DanielWStrimpel In my third example, I use curly brackets with two properties. That is creating a new object and copying one of the properties from the object passed in to `upgrade`, but `Object.assign` is modifying the original, right? Anyways performance is not really an issue to me right now, just a thought for the future. I was just looking for a nicer syntax to express upgrading an object to a child type, and the intersection looks like the best there is.